Английски alone
In английский язык, английский is an adjective. However, when we say по-английски, is английски without й a noun? I've never seen английски alone without й and язык as a noun in a sentence.

„по-английски» is an adverb which is formed from «английский».
Terence Wade (A Comprehensive Russian Grammar, 4th edition, § 382 Adverbs derived from adjectives, No. 3 Adverbs in -и), writes on this subject the following (abbreviated):

(i) Adverbs from adjectives in ‐ский/‐цкий (mostly adverbs of manner) take the ending ‐и
(ii) Those with animate connotations, including all which denote nationality, may take the prefix по‐: по‐лéнински ‘after the style of Lenin’, по‐рýсски ‘in Russian, in the Russian style’.
(iii) In some contexts, prefixed and unprefixed variants are synonymous: брáтски/по‐брáтски похлóпать по плечý ‘to slap on the shoulder in a brotherly fashion‘ etc.
(iv) In most cases, however, choice is dictated by usage: дрýжески подмигнýть ‘to wink in a friendly manner’, звéрски голóдный ‘ravenously hungry’, по‐дéтски оби́делся ‘he took childish offence’.
Note 
(a) While forms with по‐ answer the implied question подóбно комý/чемý? ‘similar to whom/what?’, forms without по‐ answer the questions как/каки́м óбразом? ‘how/in what way?’
(b) Adverbs in ‐ически cannot combine with по‐.

Considering «по-английски» vs. «английски»: According to the grammar rule cited above, the latter seems not to be wrong per se, yet has a slightly different meaning, depending on context. However, none but one of the dictionaries I checked, lists the unprefixed adverb. The „exception“ was the English wiktionary, which stated „Only used in по-англи́йски“.
Furthermore, I searched the main corpus of the Russian National Corpus for «английски», «по-английски», «немецки», «по-немецки», etc. Unprefixed variants (also excluding „по английски», or, combinations like «по-французски или английски»), are very rare.
Hence, based on this, I conclude nationality/ethnicity based adverbs should be used with prefix «по-». However, keep in mind that I am neither a native nor a proficient Russian speaker.
As a side note: Considering your previous questions, I would highly recommend you to get an introductory Russian course book and to supplement it with a grammar reference book (e.g., A Comprehensive Russian Grammar (Terence Wade), the edition of which does not matter much).

There are a lot of examples without the prefix: мастерски, дружески, залихватски, исторически, etc.

@Quassnoi Thx for the notification. I should have stated it clearer (and will accordingly edit my answer later today or tomorrow): adverbs formed from nationalities or ethnicities are usually formed with prefix «по-». Occasionally, one finds an unprefixed one, like «английски» instead of «по-английски». According to my current knowledge this is not wrong per se but very unorthodox.

@Truubehüeter Исторически так сложилось! that's both answer to "why it's so?" and an example of one without a prefix form. Or, I never saw по-исторически.

@Swift Oh, I don‘t doubt that. However, since OP asked about по-английски and английски specifically, I focused my answer on such adverbs that are derived from tribes, ethnicities, peoples etc. And it is for this specific set of adverbs that unprefixed forms seem not to be in common usage.

No, it's not a noun. Compare things like по-человечески. It's an adverb actually, and английски on its own doesn't exist.
